# Making a plot from randomly generated number in R

Tags: r, random, plot

I wonder how I can make plots from randomly generated number.

For example, if I generated random number from `rt(1000)` or `rchisq(1000)`,

I get y value for a plot.

How may I get x value from them or let me know, if there is other way to

make plots with functions.

(I won't use density function, please make plots from randomly generated number.)

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: A randomly generated number is just that, a number. There is only one value.  Sometimes people generate a lot of numbers and then make a histogram of them (or a density plot), is that what you mean?

Comment: There will be a original function and its graph. I want to make similar plot with this graph from randomly generated number from that function.

Comment: Is this what you mean: `hist(rchisq(1000, 5))` ?

Comment: Do you want those bell shaped graphs of probability distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm able to make from your question, you probably want a graph similar to probability distributions.

If that's the case then try this.

```
x <- rt(100, df=15)
dx <- dt(x, df=15)
plot(x, dx)
```

This is the plot you'll get:[image: t-distribution plot]

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I wanted. I wonder why second line gives me x values that corresponding first line.

Comment: @kdino Did you notice that this answer actually uses the density function, that you said you didn't want to use?